# How to check which relative layout is selected?

Tags: android, android-layout, datetimepicker

I am developing a reminder app. Here user click on a Relative layout which has a TextView and a button. After clicking layout user can set the time. I have set same Relative layout thrice in an activity. Now I want to set the user's selected time on the TextView with different layout clicking.

**SetReminder.java**

```
public void setTime(View v){

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.time:
            //mTimeTextHour.setText(mTime);
           setTimePicker();

            break;
        case R.id.time2:
            //mTimeTextHour.setText(mTime);
            setTimePicker();

            break;
        case R.id.time3:
            setTimePicker();
            break;

        case R.id.time4:
            setTimePicker();
            break;

    }

}

public void setTimePicker()
{
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
            this,
            now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            false
    );
    tpd.setThemeDark(false);
    tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
}
@Override
    public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        mHour = hourOfDay;
        mMinute = minute;
        if (minute < 10) {
            mTime = hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
        } else {
            mTime = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
        }

}
```

Three `TextViews` are TextView1 is in Relative_layout time ,TextView2 is in time2,TextView3 is in time3,TextView4 is in time4.

I want to set user's selected time for different layouts.

Comment: Your Question isn't clear.

Comment: which part isn't clear? @SouravBagchi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest you can do is to create variable for example `int selectedLayout`, and on click on `TextView` set this variable, for example if first `TextView` selected set `selectedLayout = 0`. Then in `onTimeSet` check `if (selectedLayout == 0)` then you know that first layout is selected.

Comment: Any time :)))))